# SoapUI and PHP Soap

Tags: php, web-services, soap, soapui

I have a doubt, I've already searched by the web but I couldn't find any response, I appreciate if you could help me :)

So, Currently I'm developing a system to interact with a WebService. My doubt is why in SoapUI if I send the request with one attribute works however with PHP SOAP I got a exception due a missing attribute...

SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <ear:getDetails>
         <ear:getDetails>
            <codeId>DpEk</codeId>
         </ear:getDetails>
      </ear:getDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

With PHP SOAP to work I need send  as well...

```
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ear:getDetails>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ear:getDetails>
            <art>3</art>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <codeId>1234</codeId>
         </ear:getDetails>
      </ear:getDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Is SoapUI fix the requests if there is a missng attributes?

Thanks!

Comment: Though I am not totally sure of your use case, just like to clarify the last point you asked. soapui does not fix request on its own other than what user has set.

Comment: @Rao thank you, what I mean is, in SoapUI the <art> element is not mandatory, however with PHP SOAP library I got an exception due a missing <art> attribute...

Comment: SoapUI can validate request on demand. You can validate the request in test step request editor by using **mouse right click and validate** or `Alt+v` key combination - this should tell if the request is valid or not in soapui. It will also provide a description of the error if the request isn't valid.

Comment: Thank you @Rao !!!! this solve my doubts, the request in SoapUi works even with invalid request, when I press the Alt+v I got the same exception in PHP SOAP line 9: Expected element 'art' instead of 'codeId' here in element getDetails@

Comment: Glad to know.There is preference in SoapUI which can be enabled if needed then you can see the same behaviour as php soap client. So that soapUI hit the web service hosted on the server if and only if valid request is valid when that property(name is not on top of my head now, but you may search online or find in `soapUI preferences`) is enabled by user.